# Apple Wallet and Google Wallet PCI compliance

Tags: security, android-pay, passbook, pci-compliance, pci-dss

We want our application to make a **Visa/Mastercard** transaction and we would like to store the card number to do recurrent transactions.
 However, we know that there are a lot of requirements to implement if we want to be **PCI** compliant.

Can we use **Apple Wallet** or **Google Wallet** to store cardholder data and access this data in our application? Is this solution **PCI** compliant?

Comment: Which country are you based in?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you will fall underneath PCI if any part of the PAN hits the card holder environment (CDE).  Even if you are forwarding it to the wallet app, the CDE is defined as any host that processes, stores, or transmits PCI governed data.   So from your description, unless you forward the transaction over to the wallet services, and the PAN is entered directly by the customer to the wallet service, your solution would fall underneath PCI.